# ViewController - how to use it properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiviewcontroller

If you have the following features, should you have two ViewControllers for the two groups of screens? or just 1 viewController for all screens message and accountprofile feature etc..?

```
MESSAGE
ViewMessages
ReadMessage
SendMessage

ACCOUNTPROFILE
ShowAccountProfile
EditAccountProfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least 3! One for MESSAGE view, one for ACCOUNTPROFILE view and one for navigating between these (Navigation controller, Tab bar controller...).

Comment: You want a viewController to have a particular concern. It's perfectly reasonable for it to control many views, but you'd want them all to be very related. The groupings you have are good ones, and Phix makes a good point about the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should mostly likely have 5 ViewControllers. A ViewController does just that: It controls or manages *a* view. So usually, for each "full screen" view, you'll use a ViewController.